# How can I take a function result as an argument for a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this program that will ask the user about the argument and transfer it to the class but I can't find how to. I tried putting the function as an argument but didn't work.

```
class Exam:
    def __init__(self, day, importance):
        self.day = day
    self.importance = importance


days = [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
    "Sunday",
]


def is_important():
    for day in days:
        answer = input("Ìs " + day + " Important")
        if answer == "True":
            return True
        elif answer == "False":
            return False


is_important() 

mon = Exam("Monday",)
tue = Exam("Tuesday", )
wed = Exam("Wednesday", )
thu = Exam("Thursday", )
fri = Exam("Friday", )
sat = Exam("Saturday", )
sun = Exam("Sunday", )

print(mon.importance)
print(tue.importance)
print(wed.importance)
print(thu.importance)
print(fri.importance)
print(sat.importance)
print(sun.importance)
```

Comment: Read about assigning function result to a variable. Then use that variable

Comment: `is_important()` will never continue the loop, because it always returns during the first iteration.

Comment: Check my answer below!

Answer (score 0):

The Exam class will be defined as follows. Here we pass both arguments and assign it to class members, we also define the `is_important` class inside it and assign the importance variable

```
class Exam:
    def __init__(self, day, importance):
        self.day = day
        self.importance = importance

    def is_important(self):

        answer = input("Ìs " + day + " Important")
        if answer == "True":
            self.importance = True
        else:
            self.importance = False
```

Then you can use individual objects to assign importance and print it

```
mon = Exam("Monday", "True")
print(mon.day)
print(mon.importance)
tue = Exam("Tueday", "False")
print(tue.day)
print(tue.importance)
#Monday
#True
#Tueday
#False
```

Or just loop to days, and call `is_important` for each day

```
days = [
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
    "Sunday",
]

exam_days = []
for day in days:
    exam_day = Exam(day)
    exam_day.is_important()
    exam_days.append(exam_day)

for exam_day in exam_days:
    print(exam_day.day)
    print(exam_day.importance)
```

The output will be

```
Ìs Monday Important True
Ìs Tuesday ImportantFalse
Ìs Wednesday ImportantFalse
Ìs Thursday ImportantTrue
Ìs Friday ImportantFalse
Ìs Saturday ImportantFalse
Ìs Sunday ImportantTrue
Monday
False
Tuesday
False
Wednesday
False
Thursday
True
Friday
False
Saturday
False
Sunday
True
```

Comment: The problem with your answer is that at every iteration of the the Exam object is overwritten, and then when the function is completed, also the last Exam runs out of scope. So if you only need the objects to print out the importance it would be fine, if you need them for further processing, your approach won't work

Answer (score 0):

`is_important()` should take the day as a parameter. Then you can call it with different days, and pass the result to the class.

```
def is_important(day):
    answer = input("Ìs " + day + " Important")
    return answer.lower() == "true"

mon = Exam("Monday", is_important("Monday");
tue = Exam("Tueday", is_important("Tuesday");
...
```

It might be better to use a dictionary rather than separate variables for each day. Then you can do:

```
exam_days = {day: Exam(day, is_important(day)) for day in days}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to make a is_important a class method. This is more pythonic and makes a clear link between the question and the weekday. Essentially it is more object oriented because the importance and asking for it are both clearly linked to the exam object. It goes like so:

```
class Exam:
    def __init__(self, day):
        self.day = day
        self.is_important()

    def is_important(self):
        answer = input("Ìs " + self.day + " Important? ")
        if answer == "Yes":
            self.importance = True
        elif answer == "No":
            self.importance = False
```

Then just initialise the Exam object for each day in a loop and add the result to a dictionary. The dictionary has the advantage, that you can initialise multiple variables and don't need to type an extra line just so they have a clear variable name. The keys of the dictionary are a better choice than ordinary variable names, if you have many objects of the same type.

```
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
        "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

my_week = {}

for day in days:
    my_week.update({day: Exam(day)})
    print my_week[day].importance
```

Answer (score 0):

In considering the problem, this might be an approach you want to consider, if having the ability to change the importance is something you want to carry with the Exam object:

```
class Exam:

    # COMMENT: set a default importance of False...
    def __init__(self, day, importance=False):
        self.day = day
        self.importance = importance

    # COMMENT: since you provide the day when the object is created,
    #     use that value (ie, self.day) in the input function call
    #     and overwrite the existing self.importance value.
    def is_important(self):
        answer = input("Ìs " + self.day + " Important?")
        if answer == "True":
            self.importance = True
        elif answer == "False":
            self.importance = False

# COMMENT: When you call the Class, you can provide it with the day 
#     and immediately provide it with an importance level.

mon = Exam("Monday", True)
tue = Exam("Tuesday", False)

# COMMENT: but you also have the flexibility to call the class and accept
#     the default importance OR overwrite it later by calling the 
#     is_important() method
wed = Exam("Wednesday")
wed.is_important()

print(mon.importance)
print(tue.importance)
print(wed.importance)
```